# Webdriver: Browser is launched. But not calls URL when GeckoDriver is used

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Actually I have installed all latest versions. My firefox browser launches. But URL is not called.

Following are my System details.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Firefox Version: 56.0
Selenium Server: selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0
GeckoDriver: geckodriver-v0.19.0-linux64

Browser Launch Code

```
if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("FF"))
            {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/geckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

}
```

I am getting following eror. Can anyone please help me in this.

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /home/vishalpachpute/workspace/ER_CustomerCare/ERCC_Login.xml

/home/vishalpachpute/workspace/ER_CustomerCare
1507724942300   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
1507724942306   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:3966
1507724942723   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.qsoDFMATTikn"
1507724942948   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1507724943785   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette

(firefox:22169): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:22169): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:22169): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:22169): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22219): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22219): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22219): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22219): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
1507724946494   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 38903
1507725070118   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1507725070153   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 2147483649
Oct 11, 2017 6:01:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1507725070269   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for "about:blank"
1507725160564   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for "about:blank"
1507725160566   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pagehide" for "about:blank"
1507725160567   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "unload" for "about:blank"
1507725160612   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "DOMContentLoaded" for "about:neterror?e=netTimeout&u=http%3A//localhost%3A8888/ercc/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=The%20server%20at%20localhost%20is%20taking%20too%20long%20to%20respond."
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=netTimeout&u=http%3A//localhost%3A8888/ercc/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=The%20server%20at%20localhost%20is%20taking%20too%20long%20to%20respond.
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'vfrootThinkPadT450', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.qsoDFMATTikn, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=LINUX, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=56.0, platformVersion=3.16.0-30-generic, moz:processID=22169, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX}]
Session ID: 12542456-e71a-40f4-944d-c476840f3c99
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:310)
    at com.vodafone.er.cc.test.integration.PlatformLayer.LaunchApplication.Execute(LaunchApplication.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:616)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

===============================================
ER
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Attached my full LaunchApplication.java file for more details

```
package com.vodafone.er.cc.test.integration.PlatformLayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
//import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import atu.testng.reports.ATUReports;
import atu.testrecorder.ATUTestRecorder;
import atu.testrecorder.exceptions.ATUTestRecorderException;

import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;



/*@Listeners({ ATUReportsListener.class, ConfigurationListener.class,
    MethodListener.class })*/

public class LaunchApplication {

    {
        System.setProperty("atu.reporter.config", "./atu.properties");

    }


    public static WebDriver driver=null;
    ATUTestRecorder recorder;
    Date date;

     @BeforeTest (alwaysRun = true)
     @Parameters({"RunUsingSG","BrowserCode","URL","Title","Platform","Version"})
    public void Execute(String RunUsingSG,String BrowserCode,String URL,String Title,String Platform,String Version) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ATUTestRecorderException
    {

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();

            //This code is for recording. if you want to do recording, just uncomment the following code. 
            /*DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            // For Recording the Execution using ATU Reporter. 
             recorder = new ATUTestRecorder("./ScriptVideos","TestVideo-" +dateFormat.format(date),false);
             recorder.start();*/

            // For IE 32 Bits
            if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("IE32"))
            { 
                dc.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
                dc.setVersion(Version);
                if(RunUsingSG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),dc);}
                else
                {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/IEDriverServer_32bit_OS.exe");
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                }
            }

            // For PhantomJS
            if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("PJS"))
            { 

                dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
                dc.setVersion(Version);
                dc.setBrowserName("Phantom JS");
                dc.setCapability("phantomjs.binary", "/AllDrivers/phantomjs");

                driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dc);

            }

            //For IE 64 Bits
            if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("IE64"))
            { 
                //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/IEDriverServer_64bit_OS.exe");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/IEDriverServer_x64_2.41.0/IEDriverServer_V2.41_64bit.exe");
                dc.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
                dc.setVersion(Version);
                if(RunUsingSG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),dc);
                }
                else
                {   
                    //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/IEDriverServer_64bit_OS.exe");
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/IEDriverServer_x64_2.41.0/IEDriverServer_V2.41_64bit.exe");

                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();}
            }


            /*//For Firefox
            if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("FF"))
            { 

                FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
                dc.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
                //dc.setVersion(Version);
                if(RunUsingSG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),dc);
                }
                else
                {
                    driver=new FirefoxDriver();

                }
            }*/

            //For Firefox GeckoDriver
            if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("FF"))
            {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/geckodriver");
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

                driver.get("URL");

            }



            // For Chrome
            if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("CH"))
            {

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("test-type");
                dc.setCapability("chrome.binary","./AllDrivers/chromedriver/");
                dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

                dc.setBrowserName("Google Chrome");
                dc.setVersion(Version);
                if(RunUsingSG.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                {
                    driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),dc);
                }
                else
                {   
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/chromedriver");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(dc);
                }
            }





            if(Platform.equalsIgnoreCase("WINDOWS"))
            try
            {
            {dc.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);}
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get(URL);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), Title);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            // ATU Reports
            ATUReports.setWebDriver(LaunchApplication.driver);
            ATUReports.indexPageDescription = "ER-CC Automation Scripts Results.";


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Reporter.log("Exception occured " +e.getMessage());
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Assert.fail();
                 driver.quit();
            }

    }



     @AfterTest
     //@Parameters({"RunUsingSG","BrowserCode","URL","Title","Platform","Version"})
    public void TearDown() throws MalformedURLException, ATUTestRecorderException
    {
         driver.close();
         //driver.quit();
         //recorder.stop();

    }
}
```

Comment: his code dont have any URL

Answer (score 0):

This code dont have any URL

```
if(BrowserCode.equalsIgnoreCase("FF")) 
{ 
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/AllDrivers/geckodriver"); 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("URL");  //add it
}
```

Comment: Hi .. Actually I added driver.get("URL") in code as you suggested. But facing same issue.  Can you please help me out in this. Thanks in advance. Also it was there already in my other if block.

Comment: Additionally I have added my LaunchApplication.java file for more details. Please check original post.

Comment: Hi. It's share above . Can you please have a look into LaunchApplication.java class

Comment: Hi I have updated selenium server and client. But facing same isssue. Can anyone please provide me solution on same.